# Should I use "like a..." or "like the one of a..." in the following sentence?

Tags: sentence, simile

What sounds more natural? This:

> Her body was warm, like the one of a sunbathing cat.

or this?

> Her body was warm, like a sunbathing cat.

(I'm open to other suggestions).

**EDIT**

Here's some context:

> She put her glass down on the floor and wrapped her arms around me.
>   Her body was warm, like the one of a sunbathing cat.

Comment: *like that of a*

Comment: @janoChen Oh you are right. But I guess using *'s* at the end is practically the same thing.

Comment: It's not the same thing -- your question was "what sounds *more natural*", right?

Comment: @Kris OK, you're right. Which one sounds more natural to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of those work. You just want:

- Her body was warm, like a sunbathing cat’s.

Answer (score 0):

Her body was warm, like the fur of a sunbathing cat.